# Filtering row of a table based on values from another table(Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have a table:

```
Month        Value1    Value2
2020-01-31    0.9       0.8
2020-02-28    0.6       0.9
2020-03-31    1.1       1.6
2020-04-30    1.5       1.8
...
2020-12-31    1.25      0.6
```

And I have second Table:

```
Column_name   Column_value
Value1_min       0.8
Value1_max       1.2
Value2_min       0.8
Value2_max       1.2
```

My Goal: I want to get rows from the first table with condition:  `Value1_min(second table) <= Value1(first table) <=Value1_max(second table) or Value2_min(second table) <= Value2(first table) <=Value2_max(second table)`

How can i do that in oracle?

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your second table exactly has the records you showed, one way could be by pivoting it and using the result in an inner join with the first table.

With your data, if you `PIVOT` over the second table, you get a single record with min and max values in four different columns:

```
SQL> with second_table(Column_name, Column_value) as
  2  (
  3      select 'Value1_min', 0.8 from dual union all
  4      select 'Value1_max', 1.2 from dual union all
  5      select 'Value2_min', 0.8 from dual union all
  6      select 'Value2_max', 1.2 from dual
  7  )
  8  select *
  9  from second_table
 10  PIVOT
 11  (
 12      min(column_value) for Column_name in ('Value1_min' as value1_min, 'Value1_max' as Value1_max, 'Value2_min' as Value2_min, 'Value2_max' as Value2_max)
 13  );

VALUE1_MIN VALUE1_MAX VALUE2_MIN VALUE2_MAX
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        .8        1.2         .8        1.2
```

Gives this, it's easy to use it in a plain `INNER JOIN` with the first table:

```
SQL> with first_table(Month, Value1, Value2) as
  2  (
  3      select date '2020-01-31', 0.9   , 0.8 from dual union all
  4      select date '2020-02-28', 0.6   , 0.9 from dual union all
  5      select date '2020-03-31', 1.1   , 1.6 from dual union all
  6      select date '2020-04-30', 1.5   , 1.8 from dual union all
  7      select date '2020-12-31', 1.25  , 0.6 from dual
  8  ),
  9  second_table(Column_name, Column_value) as
 10  (
 11      select 'Value1_min', 0.8 from dual union all
 12      select 'Value1_max', 1.2 from dual union all
 13      select 'Value2_min', 0.8 from dual union all
 14      select 'Value2_max', 1.2 from dual
 15  )
 16  select *
 17  from first_table t1
 18      inner join
 19          (
 20              select *
 21              from second_table
 22              PIVOT
 23              (
 24                  min(column_value) for Column_name in ('Value1_min' as value1_min, 'Value1_max' as Value1_max, 'Value2_min' as Value2_min, 'Value2_max' as Value2_max)
 25              )
 26          ) t2
 27          on( t1.value1 between t2.Value1_min and t2.Value1_max
 28                OR
 29              t1.value2 between t2.Value2_min and t2.Value2_max
 30             );

MONTH          VALUE1     VALUE2 VALUE1_MIN VALUE1_MAX VALUE2_MIN VALUE2_MAX
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
2020-01-31         .9         .8         .8        1.2         .8        1.2
2020-02-28         .6         .9         .8        1.2         .8        1.2
2020-03-31        1.1        1.6         .8        1.2         .8        1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

A brute force method uses correlated subqueries:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where (t1.value1 >= (select t2.column_value from table2 t2 where t2.column_name = 'value1_min') and
       t1.value1 <= (select t2.column_value from table2 t2 where t2.column_name = 'value1_max') 
      ) or
      (t1.value2 >= (select t2.column_value from table2 t2 where t2.column_name = 'value2_min') and
       t1.value2 <= (select t2.column_value from table2 t2 where t2.column_name = 'value2_max') 
      ) ;
```